# how to add multiple text fields in input box

Tags: html

[image]

when i write email then enter space tab then box is created which I mentioned in picture. I want create multiple fields and also remove in html using jquery
For e.g. you see when we ask question in stack. At the end of in which Tags fields are there box is created.

Comment: There are hundreds of tags, autosuggest plugins. Kindly look at them.

Comment: And kindly, for the way this [so] works, please accept all your previous answers.

Comment: you can refer this page how to implement multi select http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Comment: But this work only in select option tag. I want in input field and press Enter then box created